# Convert JsonConverter to System.Text.Json to support multiple primitive types and nullable

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

I am trying to convert this Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter to System.Text.Json. However, I was only able to use a single primitive type, say double and even there I cant apply the converter on nullable (double?). How can I convert this to support nullable and all number formats (float, double).

**Newtonsoft.Json**

```
public class DecimalRoundingJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly int _numberOfDecimals;

    public DecimalRoundingJsonConverter() : this(6)
    {
    }
    public DecimalRoundingJsonConverter(int numberOfDecimals)
    {
        _numberOfDecimals = numberOfDecimals;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        double input = 0;
        if (value is decimal)
        {
            var d = (decimal)value;
            input = Convert.ToDouble(d);
        }
        else if (value is float)
        {
            var d = (float)value;
            input = Convert.ToDouble(d);
        }
        else
        {
            input = (double)value;
        }
        var rounded = Math.Round(input, _numberOfDecimals);
        writer.WriteValue((decimal)rounded);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(decimal);
    }
}
```

**System.Text.Json (basic)**

```
public class DecimalRoundingJsonConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    private readonly int _numberOfDecimals = 6;
    public override double Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        double dvalue,
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        double input = (double)dvalue;
      
        var rounded = Math.Round(input, _numberOfDecimals);
        writer.WriteStringValue(rounded.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Patola, do you want to convert all the number format(e.g `decimal`/`float`) to double by using System.Text.Json.JsonConverter?

Comment: @Rena, no I want to round the number up to 5 decimal places before creating the json. Otherwise, we include unnecessary data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a converter that applies to all `float`, `double` and `decimal` values, as well as nullables of the same, by creating a `JsonConverter<object>` and overriding [`JsonConverter<object>.CanConvert(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.canconvert?view=net-6.0) to return true only for the six relevant types.

The following does the job:

```
public class RoundingJsonConverter : RoundingJsonConverterBase
{
    // The converter works for float, double & decimal.  Max number of decimals for double is 15, for decimal is 28, so throw an exception of numberOfDecimals > 28.
    public RoundingJsonConverter(int numberOfDecimals) => NumberOfDecimals = (numberOfDecimals < 0 || numberOfDecimals > 28 ? throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(numberOfDecimals)) : numberOfDecimals);
    protected override int NumberOfDecimals { get; }
}

public class RoundingTo2DigitsJsonConverter : RoundingJsonConverterBase
{
    protected override int NumberOfDecimals { get; } = 2;
}

public class RoundingTo6DigitsJsonConverter : RoundingJsonConverterBase
{
    protected override int NumberOfDecimals { get; } = 6;
}

public abstract class RoundingJsonConverterBase : JsonConverter<object>
{
    protected abstract int NumberOfDecimals { get; }

    public override object Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        typeToConvert = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert) ?? typeToConvert;
        if (typeToConvert == typeof(decimal))
            return reader.GetDecimal();
        else if (typeToConvert == typeof(double))
            return reader.GetDouble();
        else if (typeToConvert == typeof(float))
            return (float)reader.GetDouble();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case double d:
                writer.WriteNumberValue(Math.Round(d, Math.Min(15, NumberOfDecimals)));
            break;
            case decimal d:
                writer.WriteNumberValue(Math.Round(d, NumberOfDecimals));
            break;
            case float f:
                writer.WriteNumberValue((decimal)Math.Round((decimal)f, NumberOfDecimals));
            break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        typeToConvert = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert) ?? typeToConvert;
        return typeToConvert == typeof(double) || typeToConvert == typeof(decimal) || typeToConvert == typeof(float);
    }           
}
```

Notes:

- System.Text.Json has no equivalent to Newtonsoft's `JsonConverter.CanRead` so you must implement `Read()` as well as `Write()`.
- When adding the converter to `JsonSerializerOptions.Converters` use `DecimalRoundingJsonConverter` and pass the required number of digits as a constructor argument, e.g.:

  ```
  var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
  {
      Converters = { new RoundingJsonConverter(6) },
  };
  ```

  However, if you are applying the converter via attributes, Microsoft does not allow passing of converter parameters (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54187#issuecomment-869598871) for confirmation) so you will need to create a specific converter type for each required number of digits, e.g.

  ```
  public class RoundingTo2DigitsJsonConverter : RoundingJsonConverterBase
  {
      protected override int NumberOfDecimals { get; } = 2;
  }

  public class RoundingTo6DigitsJsonConverter : RoundingJsonConverterBase
  {
      protected override int NumberOfDecimals { get; } = 6;
  }
  ```

  And then apply e.g. as follows:

  ```
  [JsonConverter(typeof(RoundingTo6DigitsJsonConverter))]
  public decimal? SixDecimalPlaceValue { get; set; }
  ```
- [`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype) can be use used to get the underlying type of a nullable type such as `decimal?` or `double?`.
- `JsonConverter<T>.Write()` is never called for `null` values of nullables unless [`JsonConverter<T>.HandleNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.handlenull) is overridden to return `true`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XnOPWk).